# Firefox (10.0.2) corrupting array data

Tags: php, arrays, firefox

I am trying to cater for a user using their browser back button to access a page which contains multiple drop down lists (some are shown on selection of others using jQuery). When the user makes a room selection, advances to the next page, returns using the browser back button and makes a different selection I am resetting the drop-down lists on page load. When the user then advances again using Chrome and IE I get the following correct array structure:

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 0
                    [price] => 39.5
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 1
                    [adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                        )

                    [prices] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 49.5
                        )

                    [roomTotalPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 49.5
                        )

                    [price] => 99
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 0
                    [price] => 49
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 0
                    [price] => 39.5
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 0
                    [price] => 39.5
                )

        )
```

This is correctly showing number of 'adults' for the selected room/rate combo, room 15 and rate 15. 
When I run the exact same code in Firefox the array is getting corrupted in the following manner:

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 0
                    [price] => 39.5
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [num_rooms] => 1
                    [price] => 99
                )

            [79] => Array
                (
                    [adults] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2
                        )

                    [prices] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 49.5
                        )

                    [roomTotalPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 49.5
                        )

                )


        )
```

Rather than adding the 'adult' data to room/rate 15 it is getting added to a non existent rate '79'.

Any advice as to why Firefox might be doing this?

Comment: This is likely an issue with the code you didn't post. Please add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code to the page prevented Firefox from caching the data and resolved the issue:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
?>
```